# Why the characters never slow down when getting close to a specific object(target)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a empty GameObject with this script attached:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimatorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator[] animators;
    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 1f;

    float sp = 0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if((animators[2].transform.position - target.position).sqrMagnitude < 3)
        {
            sp += Time.deltaTime;
            sp = Mathf.Clamp(sp, 0f, 1f);
            animators[1].SetFloat("Walking Speed", sp);
            animators[2].SetFloat("Walking Speed", sp);
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 characters each one have a animator controller.
Each animator have a new state name Walking with Humanoid walk.
Each animator have a float parameter name Walking Speed in each animator it's set to 1.0

In the Inspector I added for each animator state the parameter Walking Speed.
But the 3 characters never slow down when getting close to the target.

In the screenshot each soldier both: Space_Soldier_A (4) and Space_Soldier_A (5) have the same animator controller with the Walking Speed parameter.

The medea_m_arrebola have it's own animator controller also with a Walking Speed float parameter. Same settings as for the soldiers.
All characters are walking but they never slow down when getting close to the target.

[image: Animators]

What I want to do for the idea is when the character in animators[2] the character that is a bit forward then the other two medea_m_arrebola is getting close to the target at 3 distance then start slow down and stop at distance 0.5 from the target.

This is a working solution but what if I want to make the character stop walking speed 0 at specific distance ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimatorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator[] animators;
    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 1f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(animators[2].transform.position, target.position);
        if (distanceFromTarget < 15 && distanceFromTarget > 1)
        {
            float speed = (distanceFromTarget / 15) / 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
            {
                if (speed <= 0.1f)
                {
                    animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to make that if the speed is 0.1 or less then set the speed to 0:

```
if (speed <= 0.1f)
                {
                    animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", 0);
                }
```

But it's not working the characters keep walking.
Not sure how to do it by speed to distance for example if the speed is 0.1 or less or if the distance is 1 or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is something like how i would approach this problem, in the simplest way I know how. 
You will have to add your own logic in to handle how you want them to come to a complete stop. (I.E when speed < .01f => stop), but this should get you pretty close.

```
            public void Update()
    {
        float distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
        if ( distanceFromTarget < slowDownDistance)
        {
            float speed = (distanceFromTarget / slowDownDistance)/1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is working fine. I update my code with the working code. How can I make it stop make the speed 0 so the character will not move any more ? Tried by checking the speed if it's 0.1 or less but it's not working they are keep walking. How can I make it by distance or by speed ? If the distance is less then 1 stop.

Comment: In your current logic it will only effect the speed if the character is more than one unit away from the target. My guess is it gets closer than one and then gets kicked out of that loop?